# AWS s3 bucket to ec2 file transfer using any-file npm and SFTP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, sftp

```
var AnyFile = require('any-file');
const sendFiles = require('any-file/lib');

var sf = new AnyFile();

var fromFile = "s3://BUCKET_NUM@s3.amazon.com/BUCKET_NAME/1.txt";
var toFile = "sftp://username:password@ec2_ip_addr.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/1.txt";
//var toFile = "/home/user_name/Desktop/1.txt"; //s3 to on-premise is working

try {
    sf.from(fromFile).to(toFile, function(err, res) {
        console.log(res);
        process.exit();
    });
}
catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

I'm using the 'any-file' npm library for transferring of files from AWS S3 bucket to EC2 VM, I have an SFTP server setup on my EC2, and the above code is running on my local machine.

But, when I'm sending file from s3 to ec2 the output is coming as ***true*** but file isn't getting copied, whereas while I'm trying to do the same but from s3 to local_machine output is coming ***true*** and file is getting copied successfully.

Comment: have you tried copying file from local to EC2 ? its working ?

Comment: Yes it's working from local to EC2, but s3 to EC2 isn't working if I'm using any-file npm but if i try s3 to ec2 (by using FileZilla) then the file is getting copied.

Comment: any error you are getting ?

Comment: No error is coming, I have taken an alternative approach.... I'm staging files from s3 to local, then from local to EC2